# Java MAVEN: Could not find or load main class stigastatistics.stigastatistics.StatisticsGUI

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I know, it was written here many times, but I tried solutions, but with no success. I have netbeans maven project with dependencies. I want to make executable jar file with dependencies. This is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sitgaStatistics</groupId>
<artifactId>StigaStatistics</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainClass>stigastatistics.stigastatistics.StatisticsGUI</mainClass>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>gov.nih.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
            <version>1.42</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<name>StigaStatisticsGUI</name>
</project>
```

when I clean and build projext it will create 2 jar files in target direcotry (StigaStatistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, StigaStatistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) when I start them from terminal like:
    java -jar StigaStatistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

it will respond me error: 
Error: Could not find or load main class stigastatistics.stigastatistics.StatisticsGUI

I really don't know what is wrong with this.

Thanks for answers

Comment: Post the main class code.

Comment: whole or only main function? whole class has more than 1100 lines.. the most of it is swing generated code for creating buttons, textfileds actions on it etc.

Comment: I want to know the package name.

Comment: in StatisticsGUI.java:
package sitgastatistics.stigastatistics;

Comment: I think your problem is that you mispelled the name of the main class, i.e.  you do not really have class named stigastatistics.stigastatistics.StatisticsGUI   Did you just say your package ist sitgastatistics.stigastatistics? See the typo?

Comment: I'm an idiot... I didn't find this typo for a year in my package name.. Now it's running.. thanks a lot

Comment: Added that as an answer with the plea to accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the misspelled fully-qualified name of the main class. There is a typo in the first part of the package name.

Either rename the package `sitgastatistics.stigastatistics` or correct the `<mainClass>stigastatistics.stigastatistics.StatisticsGUI</mainClass>` property definition so that the package name reads the same.